# Apply a written code to all CSV files across different folders using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a wide range of CSV files that give me the solar energy produced by several systems on a daily basis. Each CSV file corresponds to one day in the year, for one particular site (I have 12 sites).

My goal is to develop a code that reads all CSV files (located across different folders), extracts the daily produced solar energy for every specific day and site, stores the values in a dataframe, and finally exports the dataframe collecting all daily produced solar energy across all sites on a new Excel file.

So far I have written the code to extract the values of all CSV files stored within the same folder, which gives me the solar energy produced for all days for which a CSV file exists in that folder:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

path = r"C:\Users\XX\Documents\XX\DataLogs\NameofSite\CSV\2020\02\CSV\*.csv"
Monthly_PV=[]

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df=pd.read_csv(fname, header=7, decimal=',')
    kWh_produced=df["kWh"]
    daily_start=kWh_produced.iloc[0]
    daily_end=kWh_produced.iloc[-1]
    DailyPV=daily_end-daily_start
    Monthly_PV.append(DailyPV)

print(Monthly_PV)
MonthlyTotal=sum(Monthly_PV)
Monthly_PV=pd.DataFrame(Monthly_PV)
print(MonthlyTotal)
Monthly_PV.to_excel(r"C:\Users\XXX\Documents\XXX\DataLogs\NameofSite\CSV\2020\02\CSV\Summary.xlsx")
```

I get the result I want: a list in which each value corresponds to the daily produced solar energy of each CSV in this one given folder located on the folder I called "path". My aim is to add something to this code so that the developed code is applied to CSV files located in previous folders to the one listed here as well, or to parallel folders within the same bigger folder.

Any tips will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra `for` loop to handle a list of paths

```
import numpy as np
import glob

paths = [r"C:\Users\XX\Documents\XX\DataLogs\NameofSite\CSV\2020\02\CSV\*.csv",
    r"C:\Foo\*.csv",
    r"..\..Bar]*.csv"]

Monthly_PV=[]

for path in paths:
    for fname in glob.glob(path):
        df=pd.read_csv(fname, header=7, decimal=',')
        kWh_produced=df["kWh"]
        daily_start=kWh_produced.iloc[0]
        daily_end=kWh_produced.iloc[-1]
        DailyPV=daily_end-daily_start
        Monthly_PV.append(DailyPV)

print(Monthly_PV)
MonthlyTotal=sum(Monthly_PV)
Monthly_PV=pd.DataFrame(Monthly_PV)
print(MonthlyTotal)
Monthly_PV.to_excel(r"C:\Users\XXX\Documents\XXX\DataLogs\NameofSite\CSV\2020\02\CSV\Summary.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to hardcode a list of directories in your program, maybe try something based on this?

```
def get_input_directories(depth: int, base_directory: str) -> typing.DefaultDict[str, typing.List[DeltaFile]]:
    """
    Build a dict with keys that are directories, and values that are lists of filenames.

    Does not include blocking uninteresting tracks.
    """
    result: typing.DefaultDict[str, typing.List[DeltaFile]] = collections.defaultdict(list)

    os.chdir(base_directory)

    try:
        for root, directories, filenames in os.walk('.'):
            if root.count('/') != depth:
                # We only want to deal with /band/album (for EG, with depth==2) in root
                continue
            assert not directories, f"root is {root}, directories is {directories}"
            for filename in filenames:
                if appropriate_extension(filename) and not hidden(filename):
                    result[root].append(DeltaFile(filename))
    finally:
        os.chdir('..')

    return result
```

You can safely remove the type annotations if you don't want them.